# Getting OpenX (Ad Software) republish.php to work

Tags: php, openx

I'm trying to run republish.php (part of OpenX) to re-process some statistics data. When I do I get the following error:

C:\apache\htdocs\scripts\maintenance\tools>C:\php\php.exe -f republish.php 'ads.  ourdomain.ca' '2012-11-09 01:00:00' '2012-11-12 14:00:00'

The end date passed into the republish.php script is not a valid operation interval end date. 
Please pass in the end date in '%Y-%M-%d %H:%m:%s' format.

The republish.php script will NOT be run.

I've reviewed the PHP date/time functions and I think I have the date/time formated correctly so I don't understand why the script refuses to run. Any one else have any suggestions or experience doing this?

Comment: I've noticed that if I add var_dump($argv); to the script that php is parsing the dates wrong. If I change the single quotes around the date/times to double quotes that seems to help. But the script still refuses to run with the same error (The end date passed into the republish.php script is not a valid operation interval end date. Please pass in the end date in '%Y-%M-%d %H:%m:%s' format.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The end date had to be 2012-11-12 14:59:59 (basically the end of the hour instead of the beginning of the next hour)